# Get last order date customer in odoo partner view

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

How can I get the last confirmed sales order date in my odoo partner view
for example

Customer J. Do last purchase : 10/03/2018 / 50 days ago
Is there a module for this or how can I make a computed field with only access to odoo GUI & developer mode.

I tried:

```
lines = self.env['sale.order'].sorted(
  [('partner_id', '=', company_id),
  key=lambda l: l.date_order, reverse=True)
  self.x_last_order = lines[:1].date_order
```

So I adjusted my compted field to:
[image]

But i stil don't get a result or error.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot or the XML code of the view where you would like to see this value ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `order` and `limit` parameters of `search` method:

```
last_confirmed_order = self.env['sale.order'].search(
    [('partner_id', '=', company_id)],
    order='date_order desc',
    limit=1
)
```

**EDIT**

If you're using the interface to create the computed field, may be your problem is this:

> The field **Compute** is the Python code to compute the value of the field
>   on a set of records. The value of the field **must be assigned** to each
>   record with a **dictionary-like assignment**.

So let's try this:

```
for record in self:
    last_confirmed_order = self.env['sale.order'].search(
        [('partner_id', '=', record.company_id)],
        order='date_order desc',
        limit=1
    )
    record['x_last_order'] = last_confirmed_order.date_order
```

But I have to say that the domain of the search doesn't look very well, I mean, why are you comparing the ID of a partner to the ID of a company?

Comment: I didn't realized you were using the interface to create the field, take a look at my edited answer then.

Comment: Sorry the domain was a mistake stil new to odoo. But thx to your code the field is working!